# Can bundler use locally installed gems when a custom source is specified

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have a project where we are building a custom gem which is hosted on a private gemserver (gemfury). This gem is a dependency in multiple Gemfiles where I need to run tests.

So I have a Gemfile that looks like this:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

source 'https://gem.fury.io/custom/' do
  gem 'my-custom-gem', '0.0.42'
end

gem 'aws-sdk-iotdataplane', '~>1.15.0'
gem 'bson', '~>4.4.2'
gem 'mongoid', '~>6.1.1'
.
.
.
```

I build and install the gem locally with `rake install` (which works fine) and then attempt to run `bundle install` on the above Gemfile.

I get the following error:

```
$ bundle install

Fetching gem metadata from https://gem.fury.io/custom/..
Could not find gem 'my-custom-gem (= 0.0.42)' in rubygems repository https://gem.fury.io/custom/ or installed locally.
The source contains the following versions of 'my-custom-gem': 0.0.1, 0.0.4
```

It is my understanding that if the gem is installed locally on the system, bundler should not attempt to fetch it from the source.

Is this correct?

If I remove the custom source block from around the gem line, it will use the local gem and the fact that the error message says "... or installed locally" really seems to suggest this should work.

Comment: Are you sure `0.0.42` is actually installed locally the meesage seems to suggest that "0.0.1" and "0.0.4" are available but not "0.0.42"

Comment: @engineersmnky yes. `gem list` shows that and many other versions (0.0.42, 0.0.5, 0.0.4, 0.0.3, 0.0.2, 0.0.1, 0.0.1.pre123, 0.0.1.pre42). 0.0.1 and 0.0.4 are actually the only versions on the gemserver though.

Comment: I am also using gemfury for this setup. I believe that bundler still must be able to access the defined source to fetch the index, even when the gem is installed. You can try using the `--local` flag.

Comment: @DannyB `--local` does not seem to help. It can access the source and with the `-V` flag I can see that it does pull a list of versions from the source (even with --local). Version 0.0.42 does not exist on the source yet since that is the version I am trying to test.

Comment: I think your simplest bet is to just `export BUNDLE_GEM__FURY__IO` with a deploy token in any machine (dev or CI) that needs it (with CI, as a secret of course) - this is how I am doing it, and then it is transparent to all.

Comment: @DannyB I'm not sure I understand how that is related. The machine has a token and is accessing gemfury, but the gem version that was just built and not yet tested has not been pushed to gemfury.

Comment: If you are testing the gem itself, then it should not be required in the Gemfile, nor in the Gemfile.lock or gemspec. It should not even be built (for the test purposes at least).

Comment: @DannyB I am not testing the gem itself per-se, or rather that was done in a previous step before it was built. In this step I am trying to test it inside an AWS lambda which includes it via a Gemfile.